# Text appearing with delay

Tags: javascript, delay

I'm trying to find the solution that how can i make a text appear on the page after 10 seconds of page load? example text..

```
I didn't do anything, because I think it's about javascript here...
```

Example : Something like this: http://postimg.org/image/duogy83zd/

Comment: I have no clue what you're even talking about. Nothing about this question is helpful in any way.

Comment: LOL. I want something like this... http://postimg.org/image/duogy83zd/

Comment: I don't know what is so hard to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, thats what you need :

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var theDelay = 10;
  var timer = setTimeout("showText()",theDelay*1000)
}
function showText(){
  document.getElementById("delayedText").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="delayedText" style="visibility:hidden">
I didn't do anything, because I think it's about javascript here...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```